# How to display pdf in frontend Angular from fetched binary data ( Binary data is one the element of received an object from REST API)?

Tags: html, angular, mongodb, typescript, pdf

In MongoDB 'certificate' collection have '_id, studentID, file' fields. Simply I can input for each document where data type for '_id' and 'studentID' are the string, and file data type is Binary (this binary auto-generated by MongoDB during insertion for each user pdf file).

From fetched data, I can display into angular (e.g StudentID, SchoolName) but only I can't display pdf from fetched binary data into angular

In node server: (app.js) // given the core code to avoid too long reading

// This for inserting data into MongoDB

```
**var fs = require('fs');  
var pdfBinary = fs.readFileSync("./TestingPurpose.pdf"); 
var pdf = new mongodb.Binary(pdfBinary);**
db.collection('Test').insert({                    
                 dateTime: new Date(dateTime),
                 studentName: studentName,
                 Principal: principalName,
                 file: pdf }
```

- After successfully data importing in MongoDB can see data in MongoDB as below:

  {
      "_id" : "C1135",
      "dateTime" : ISODate("2019-01-23T11:45:52.254+01:00"),
      "studentID" : "stu123",
      "schoolName" : "XXX Primary School",
      **"file" : BinData(0,"JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2Jq...  more 101410 bytes - application/pdf"**)
  }

---

**certificate.model.ts**: file

```
export class Certificate {
  _id: string;
  dateTime: string;
  studentID: string;
  schoolName: string;
  file: any;
}
```

---

Then in Frontend Angular use (**user.service.ts**) to receive all infro from Node (**app.js**)::

```
import { Certificate } from '../model/certificate.model';
cert: Certificate[];
  // receiving all students info
getCertificates() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5600/aziz/displayAllCertificates');
  }
// to get always get an instant update I use refreshGetCertificates()
  refreshGetCertificates() {
    this.chkSubscrip = this.getCertificates().subscribe((res) => {
      this.cert= res as Certificate[];
    });
  }
```

---

In Certificate Component:
(certificate.component.ts):

```
export class CertificatesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      myPDF: any;
      constructor(
         public userService: UserService,
         private dialog: MatDialog,
  ) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.refreshGetCertificates();
  }
 pdfView(receiveObj) {

    this.forPDF = !this.forPDF;
    const myUint8 = new Uint8Array(receiveObj);
    this.myPDF= myUint8;
  }
}
```

---

(certificate.component.html):

```
<div class="rows">
  <ul class="settings_test headerclass text-center">
    <li style="float: left">ID</li>
    <li>Student-ID</li>
    <li>School</li>
    <li>PDF View</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let eachCerts of userService.cert">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="settings_test">
      <li style="width:10%">{{eachCerts._id}}</li>
      <li style="width:10%">{{eachCerts.studentID}}</li>
      <li style="width:10%">{{eachCerts.schoolName}}</li>
      <li style="width:10%"> <button (click) ="pdfView(eachCerts.file)">  View as PDF </button></li>
      <object *ngIf=forPDF data="{{myPDF}}" ></object>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In each row will show ID, StudentID, SChool-Name and a button('View as PDF'), when the button will be clicked then a popup or a new window will appear to display the pdf file from the fetched pdf binary data.

Comment: So, you are basically saying that you cannot open the PDF in a new browser tab or download it at all? What is actual behavior or output?

Comment: Thanks Yes, you got me. In console show me about error: 
ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)......at DomSanitizerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitiz
____
Sorry, I am not knowledgable in Angular, so do not know exactly how to say about the error. I think about url trust issue.

Comment: This question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154874/angular-6-downloading-file-from-rest-api/52687792#52687792

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 Downloading file from rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154874/angular-6-downloading-file-from-rest-api)

Comment: @Pier, First of all, I have not that much knowledge of programming but I am learning and love to do. 
I have seen your given link but it didn't work for me. I get an object from REST API and in the object, there has an element that keeps binary data (data type of string) for pdf. And then I need to display the pdf. Help me, please. I am totally lost for that.

Comment: Ok, what I posted works for binary data. You may recycle everything I gave to you by converting the "string containing the binary data" into truly binary data. How is the string encoded? Base64?

Comment: @Pier Thanks for your efforts but unfortunately I couldn't manage it. 
the pdf encoded as
**var pdfBinary = fs.readFileSync("./TestingPurpose.pdf"); 
            var pdf = new MongoDB.Binary(pdfBinary);**
I will post the sequence simply with short and details now. Really a new and poor programmer it is killing me and I think it quite complicated too :(

Comment: I updated the answer. Check if it fits now.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154874/angular-6-downloading-file-from-rest-api) that should solve your issue, with this modification:

At the beginning, you have to convert your data into a blob. In your case that would be:

```
public getPDFFromFile(file /* place here the correct type of your class*/): Blob {   
    return new Blob([file.buffer])
}
```

then you should be able to use the above mentioned answer. As note by MongoDB documentation, you can access the internal binary data via the `buffer` property which is of type `Buffer`.

Comment: sure if you had the chance to look on my code it would be solved a long time before. Think so because of my lack of knowledge in programming I am suffering from that. I am trying if I can't then I will try to upload in git to share the complete code then kindly help me to solve it, please. I feel so shy and guilty to bother you guys and thanks in advance. :)