# How to open/display text file content coming from backend in modal window using angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new to angular and looking for a solution where I can select a text file from a list of text files coming from back-end using a checkbox and display its content on click of a button let's say [View Content] in modal window or a dialog box.

The meta-data of all files visible is to be displayed in a table at front-end.

The backend API fetching the file details just provide the id,URL,fileName in json format displayed in a table and files are stored in the file repo lets say google drive.

Any working solution link will be helpful to understand the implementation.

Comment: Maybe this other topic can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52154874/6433166

Answer (score 0):

Just make a request and get the file by url using angular http client. And then you can use some library to display it according to the file type.

PS: Image can be fetched directly.

Comment: The solution of using a third party document viewer service I have already tried and working fine but  I am looking for a solution where I can show the content only in a modal window without using a third party service.

Any good server-side open source library to achieve this is will also work..!!

Comment: Only text file from the back-end API.

Comment: `this.http.get("app/files/1.txt", { responseType: 'text' as 'json'}).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.text());
}) `


Try this.


Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053328/angular-4-how-to-read-content-of-text-file-with-httpclient