# Angular 9 - How to download files instead of opening them in the browser?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to download a file using an **ANGULAR** based app, but the file which can be read by HTML 5 are shown in the browser instead of being downloaded. Most of the provided solution online are related to HTML/PHP programming, but they are not helpful in the case of **ANGULAR**. The code which I'm using is as following:

html:

```
<button  (click)="download()">Download!</button>
```

typescript:

```
download(){
    window.open('http://localhost/test/uploads/file.mp4');
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154874/angular-6-downloading-file-from-rest-api

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek, Concerning the typescript part (front end) it may be helpful, but the back end part (I think the java was used for it) is very ambiguous to me. Is there a similar case with php?